# Script to open vlc with local ip and port

Tags: 14.04, bash, vlc, ip

I am trying to create a script to open vlc with my local ip and port 8888.
My current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
vlc http://10.0.0.1:8888/
```

This works fine, but when I go to another network the local ip changes to 10.0.0.64, and the script is useless. I managed find my new local ip by using:

```
hostname -I
```

**The new script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

a="http://"
b=":8888/"
ip="$(hostname -I)"

final=${a}${ip}${b}

vlc $final
```

But this dosen't work.

```
echo $final
http://10.0.0.0.1 :8888/
```

Hmmm...

Why does my variable have a space in it and how can I remove it?
Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `hostname -i` lists all IP addresses of the host, this can be more than one. The IP addresses are separated by spaces. The function is just a bit "lazy" and puts a space after every IP address, even if it's only one.

You could remove the space at the end, but if your host has more than one IP address this script will still fail.

It's better to use this instead (as explained [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-the-ip-address-assigned-to-eth0-and-display-ip-only/)):

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

You should replace `eth0` by the interface you want the IP address of.

So your script becomes (I also made it a bit shorter as you can see):

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`

vlc "http://${IP}:8888/"
```

Comment: Thanks times a million, works like a charm! You saved my night Louis!